# jQuery ajax callback using websocket

Tags: jquery, ajax, websocket

I saw people doing the following to make a JQuery Ajax callback

```
    function getData() {
        return $.ajax({
        url : 'example.com',
        type: 'GET'
        });
    }

    function handleData(data /* , textStatus, jqXHR */ ) {
        alert(data);
        //do some stuff
    }

    getData().done(handleData);
```

I am just wondering say I have a websocket like the following

```
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/...");
```

How do I use the ws to make the call to the server?

Comment: have you tried looking at a WebSocket tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications#Sending_data_to_the_server?

Comment: Thanks, it seems I don't need ajax anymore if I use websocket.... awesome!!!